# How can I unhide objects? All the objects are shown in the layer tab

Tags: objects

How can I unhide objects? All the objects are shown in the layer tab

[image: only one object is shown. but im sure i didnt hide any other object]

Only one object is shown. but I'm sure I didn't hide any other object.

Answer (score 0):

You must have pressed <kbd>/</kbd> which switch your view to *Local* (it isolates the selected object(s)).
To exit *Local* view, press <kbd>/</kbd> again

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've edited  ;)